# Wordpress Multisite url remapping

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, permalinks, multisite

I'm currently using a complex multisite setup. I have the site as the landing page/blog and another site for the main functionality. The subdomain of the main site is set to `/dashboard/` so every other page that loads after has the dashboard slug in it. IE `www.name.com/dashboard/post-a-project`.

Is there was a way to make the website appear as `www.name.com/post-a-project` while not interfering with the landing page site? This is mostly for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dashboard/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

I've set it to a temporary redirect using `R=302`. If this works for you then change it to `R=301` to make it a permanent redirect.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.